# TensorFlow LSTM length output

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, lstm

So basically I have an LSTM model which takes in a bunch of numbers (These numbers are actually music notes that I changed into numbers. My goal is to create computer generated music if you were wondering). The issue I am running into is that I do not know how to make a prediction. What I want the computer to output is a list (or string or whatever it can) of numbers that follows whatever rules it came up with during the training proccess. In previous projects, I only knew how to output 1 prediction number, giving the computer some data to predict on, but I want a completely new list without giving the computer a starting value. Preferably the computer can generate more than 1 number at a time.

Here is the code that I currently have. It does not work right now:

```
n_steps = 1
X, y = split_sequence(data, n_steps)
X = X.reshape((X.shape[0], X.shape[1], 1))
X = tf.cast(X, dtype='float32')

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(256, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
#model.add(Dropout(0.2)) # I am not sure what this is, but it doesn't break my code
model.add(LSTM(128, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
#model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(128))
#model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['mae'])

model.fit(X, y, epochs=10, batch_size=2, verbose=2)


prediction = model.predict(X) # I want to output a list of numbers
print(prediction)
```

Now, my prediction is outputting a realy long list of lists containing the same value which I think is the one prediction. It looks like this:

```
[[62.449333]
 [62.449333]
 [62.449333]
 ...
 [62.449333]
 [62.449333]
 [62.449333]]
```

I want a list that is not a prediction, but more like a GAN output of a brand new list of numbers. Also, I am not sure why this prediction is outputing a really long list of lists.

data looks something like this, it is shortened for brevity:

```
[64, 76, 64, 75, 64, 76, 64, 75, 64, 76, 64, 71, 64, 74, 64, 72, 69, 64, 45, 64, 52]
```

The x train looks like this when n_steps = 1:

```
[[64], [76], [64], [75], [64], [76], [64], [75], [64], [76], [64], [71], [64], [74]]
```

and y looks like this, with each one being the expectpected output for the corresponding x train:

```
[76, 64, 75, 64, 76, 64, 75, 64, 76, 64, 71, 64, 74, 64]
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Input shape for LSTM is `[batch, timesteps, feature]` While you are providing a single number.

Comment: `Softmax` activation is used for multiclass classification, I believe this is a  regression task.

Comment: Yes, I changed it to linear and I solved some issues there. What do you mean by I am inputting a single number into the LSTM?

Comment: It means that you need to change the input to something like: `model.add(LSTM((256,), activation='relu', return_sequences=True))`

Comment: Can we see your training data? What do your x inputs and y output labels look like?

Comment: My model is now completely updated (I think), and my main issue now is that I want to have the model output a brand new set of numbers that has a length longer  than 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the structure of your model is fine but the data needs some work. Your LSTM is only set up to output 1 value, which you can see with your last LSTM layer not having `return_sequences=True`. The fact that your y labels have multiple values must be confusing the model.

I think you should keep this behaviour, but edit your input/output data as follows:

If one sequence in your data is:

```
[64, 76, 64, 75, 64, 76, 64, 75, 64, 76, 64, 71, 64, 74, 64, 72, 69, 64, 45, 64, 52]
```

Then your training examples and labels should be:

```
x[0] = [64]
y[1] = [76]

x[1] = [64, 76]
y[1] = [64]

x[2] = [64, 76, 64]
y[2] = [75]
```

Every step of the sequence can be a separate training example, but each y label should only be one output.

Your linear output could work, but I think this may work better as a categorical problem with a softmax output. The final dense layer should have the number of possible notes that your model can output. You would also have to pad these sequences with 0 values so that all your x input values are the same length, so `x` values would actually be:

```
x[0] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 64]
x[1] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 64, 75]
```

etc. with the length of the array being your max sequence length.

When it comes to predicting, use a loop. You'd give the model a one value inut sequence, then append the predicted note to the input sequence and feed it back to the model again:

```
seed_note = [64] # initial note to give the model
next_notes = 10 # how many notes to predict

for _ in range(next_notes):
    token_list = pad_sequences(seed_note, maxlen=max_sequence_len, padding='pre') # pad sequence with 0s
    predicted = np.argmax(model.predict(token_list), axis=-1) # get best prediction for next note
    seed_note += [predicted]
    
print(seed_text)
```

Comment: This is extremely helpful information, but I think there may be a small misunderstanding. My y labels are 1 long list with each label being an integer in the set, not a bunch of long lists. Also, without changing the x and y data but changing the output activation to 'softmax' I just get a bunch of 1s as output. Is that supposed to happen or do I have to change my data before the softmax output works? Thanks!

Comment: Also, how do I import 'max_sequence_len'?

Comment: I'm assuming your given data `[64, 76, 64, 75, 64, 76, 64, 75, 64, 76, 64, 71, 64, 74, 64, 72, 69, 64, 45, 64, 52]` is one example of a song/tune that you'd like your model to learn from. If you have multiple songs, you'd have to process each of these into x inputs and y outputs as I have described, where one song can give multiple training examples.

Comment: Using a softmax activation is for when you have categorical data. The resultant output is a one-hot vector with probabilities of each cateogory being the correct prediction, and these probabilities are normalised to total to 1. A softmax with only 1 output will not work. If you have 100 possible notes, your dense layer should have 100 neurons.

Comment: max_sequence_len is something you define. You can get it from your data. The example data you gave is 21 integers long, so you could set `max_sequence_len = 21` unless you have longer songs in your data set. Just set it to the length of the longest song.

Comment: Your explanation and answer have been very helpful and I really appreciate your time and effort here. I am going to mark this response as the accepted one because I believe many others will find their answer in this response, however, I am still a bit hazy on the softmax activation. Would you mind taking a look at my new question which clarifies everything a bit? Thank you so much! Here is the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66642948/tensorflow-lstm-predicting-same-value-error

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that 1) you want to output a list of different predictions (i.e. you are concerned by the fact that each prediction takes the same value). 2) you want a list of floats rather than a list of lists containing floats.

Working backwards:

2, When making predictions using neural networks and `model.predict()`, it outputs an array of lists when fed several x_test samples - this is easily solvable by using `ndarray.flatten()` thus in your case: `prediction = model.predict(X).flatten()`

1, I would first investigate that you are reshaping your input data correctly. LSTM models takes 3D data as inputs and thus expects a 3D array, in the form (sequence, timestep, feature):

Sequence, is the total number of sequences in your dataset (or observations/samples)

Timestep, corresponds to the size of your sequences

Feature, is the number of observations at a timestep (/number of variables)

you have therefore defined only one feature for each timestep. If this is the case you are feeding it (x.shape[0] number of samples, with x.shape[1] number of timesteps in the sequence, with only 1 feature/variable) - is this your intention? It would be helpful to get more info on the data being used i.e. number of features and desired window size for sequence.

Comment: To be frank, I have no idea really what is going on in the reshape, but I do understand that I need to input a 3d shape to the LSTM. I think that I just found this reshape set up on a random online tutorial. Do you recommend another way to reshape my data into a 3d shape? Otherwise very helpful and explanatory, +1 vote! Also, the flatten just changes the list of lists into 1 list with a the same bunch of values. I want to output many different values.

Comment: I am suspicious of how the data has been reshaped, i.e. whether it has been done correctly for your desired output - this can be solved with more insight into what your x_data actually is (so more info here would be helpful :) ). When you say you'd like to output many different values - are you troubled by the fact that your model is only outputting 1 identical value repeated or you would like an output of different shape? (it is important to bare in mind that your model will only output a column vector of values/predictions i.e. as is the y_train or y_test).

Comment: What I mean by outputting a list of numbers is what I want my model to output a list of different numbers. For example, if I gave my model the numbers: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, I want the model to output something like: 2, 3, 4, 5, 6. Similar to a GAN model but for text